# Using rvest to scrape data that is not in table

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website.  I thought I could use rvest, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting data that is not in a table.

I don't know if it's possible, or whether I'm using the wrong package?

I am trying to get the website, name and address from the following html:

```
<div class="info clearfix">
<i class="sprite icon title"></i>
<p class="title">
<a target="_blank" href="https://test.com/regions/Tennis_Court.html">
Tennis Court</a>
</p>
<p class="location"> 123 Page St, Charlestown</p>                                                <p class="excerpt" itemprop="description">A place to play tennis</p>                                                                                           </div>
```

I'd hoped I could use something like html_node("title") etc, but that doesn't seem to wrong.  Am I completely on the wrong path?

Comment: Can you share the url from where you are trying to extract the data and clarify what data you want to extract exactly?

Comment: @RonakShah I was using https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars and trying to extract the name, address and the link to their page (eg.  the first one is "Holy Hop", "498 New North Road, Kingsland" and "https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars/holy-hop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `html_nodes` to add css selectors to extract :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars'

webpage <- url %>% read_html()
name <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.name a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
address <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.address') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
links <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.name a') %>% html_attr('href')
data.frame(name, address, links)

#                              name                                address
#1                         Holy Hop          498 New North Road, Kingsland
#2                              Sly          354A Karangahape Road, Newton
#...
#...

                                                                      
#                                                                 links
#1                         https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars/holy-hop
#2                              https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars/sly
#...
#...
```