# Loop with rvest

Tags: r

I'm very new to all this and am trying to work through some examples on stackoverflow to build up my confidence.

I found this answer by @RonakShah

[Using rvest to scrape data that is not in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928540/using-rvest-to-scrape-data-that-is-not-in-table/62928835#62928835)

and thought I'd use it because I'm familiar with HTML to build up my confidence with loops.

My issue is that I can't make the loop work.

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong?  It's bits and pieces of code I've found through the messageboards, but I'm not getting anywhere!

```
library(rvest)

page<- (0:2)
urls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(page)) {
  url<- paste0("https://concreteplayground.com/sydney/bars?page=",page[i])
  urls[[i]] <- url
}


tbl <- list()


j <- 1
for (j in seq_along(urls)) {
  tbl[[j]] <- urls[[j]] %>%   read_html()
  name <- tbl[[j]] %>% html_nodes('p.name a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  address <- tbl[[j]] %>% html_nodes('p.address') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
  links <- tbl[[j]] %>% html_nodes('p.name a') %>% html_attr('href')
  data.frame(name, address, links)
  j <- j+1                    
}

#convert list to data frame
tbl <- do.call(rbind, tbl)
```

Comment: in your code, delete `j<-1` and `j=j+1`

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't work either.

Comment: what exactly do you need from the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create urls using `paste0` directly, no need for a loop.

```
library(rvest)
pages <- 1:2
urls <- paste0("https://concreteplayground.com/sydney/bars?page=", pages)
```

If you put the code on that page in a function, you can use it with `map_df` to get combined dataframe directly. `map_df` does the job of `for` loop and `do.call(rbind, tbl)` together.

```
get_web_data <- function(url) {
  webpage <- url %>% read_html()
  name <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.name a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  address <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.address') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
  links <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.name a') %>% html_attr('href')
  data.frame(name, address, links)
}

purrr::map_df(urls, get_web_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak - I'd tried something similar and got an "Error: `map_df()` requires dplyr" (even though i've definitely installed and loaded the dplyr package).  I'm still getting an error when I try your code too...

Comment: That's strange, it works for me though without any error. Can you restart R and try it on fresh R session?

Comment: I guess you have R version < 4.0.0. Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` call like `data.frame(name, address, links, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and try again.