# Rvest returning null values

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to piece together how rvest is used, and I thought I'd got it but all the results I receive are null.

I am using @RonakShah 's example ([Loop with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006772/loop-with-rvest/63006812#63006812)) as my base example and thought I'd try and expand to instead collect the name, telephone and hours open each day:

```
site = "https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars/archie-brothers-cirque-electriq"

get_phone <- function(url) {
  webpage <- site %>% read_html()
name <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.name') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  telephone <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.telephone') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  monday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  tuesday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  wednesday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  thursday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  friday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  saturday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  sunday <- webpage %>% html_nodes('p.day a') %>%html_text() %>% trimws()
  data.frame(telephone, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday)
}

get_phone(site)
```

But I can't get any of these to work individually?  I can't even get it to read the day in or the incorrect phone number.  Would someone help point out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the webpage, select `Inspect` and check the HMTL of the webpage. Find the element that you want to extract and use CSS selectors to scrape it.

```
library(rvest)
site <- "https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/bars/archie-brothers-cirque-electriq"

get_phone <- function(url) {
  webpage <- site %>% read_html()
  phone <- webpage %>% html_nodes('span[itemprop="telephone"]') %>% html_text()
  opening_hours <- webpage %>% 
                    html_nodes('div.open-hours') %>% 
                    html_attr('data-times') %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
  list(phone_number = phone, opening_hours = opening_hours)
}

get_phone(site)


#$phone_number
#[1] "+64 800 888 386"

#$opening_hours
#  weekday time_from time_to
#1       1     12:00   00:00
#2       2     12:00   00:00
#3       3     12:00   00:00
#4       4     12:00   00:00
#5       5     12:00   00:00
#6       6     10:00   00:00
#7       0     10:00   00:00
```

Opening hours are stored in a json file which is helpful so we don't have to individually scrape them and bind them together.

Comment: Any tips on how I can replace the numeric weekdays with the names?

Comment: You could create a vector `days <- c('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')` and then use `weekday` to subset it. `days[opening_hours$weekday + 1]`