# Exists vs is.null in Rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to edit an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008052/13966949) so that I can check if the element in rvest exists before scraping it.

I can skip the phone element if there is no number, because the phone element always exists (see below).

However the "opening_hours" element doesn't always exist, so I'm trying to work out a way that if element doesn't exist it is skipped over (because otherwise the code breaks).

I thought i might be able to use 'exists' or 'is.null' in an if statement, but both fail.

```
site <- "https://concreteplayground.com/sydney/bars/chiswick-at-the-gallery"

get_phone <- function(url) {
  webpage <- url %>% read_html()
  phone <- webpage %>% html_nodes('span[itemprop="telephone"]') %>% html_text()
  if(is_empty(phone)) phone = "NA"
  opening_hours <- webpage %>% 
    html_nodes('div.open-hours') %>% 
    html_attr('data-times') %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
  data.frame(webpage = url, phone_number = phone, opening_hours = opening_hours, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

get_phone(site)
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible strategy is open use the `html_node()` function instead of `html_nodes()`.  The difference between the two function is `html_node()` will always return 1 value.  If the node does not exist then `html_node()` will return a NA.
One can then check for the NA and handle accordingly.

```
library(rvest)

#url<-"https://concreteplayground.com/sydney/restaurants/north-sandwiches-cafe"
url<-"https://concreteplayground.com/sydney/bars/chiswick-at-the-gallery"

page<-read_html(url)
hours <- page %>% html_node("div.open-hours") 
   
if (!is.na(hours) ) {
   openhours<-hours %>% html_attr('data-times') %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
   print(openhours)
} else {
   openhours <- NA
   print("no hours found")
}
```